# how to store json file at server using asp.net as server side language and how to access json data using javascript, html and css?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, json

I am a newbie in web development. I am in the process of building a food blog website. I want to pursue front-end-web-developer career. I have built my website only using client side languages like javascript, jquery, html and css. I have used json to store the data. my questions are -
1. I now want to make my website live. For that I want my website to be hosted on server. As I am not using any server side scripting, would my data related to website be visible to everyone if they do try to "inspect element" or "view source"? 
2. how can I separate Json from client side code/scripting? I think for that I will have to seperate json data from other javascript code and store it into a separate file on a server. But in that case how can I access the Json data? For that I will have to make use of some server side scripting language. I prefer Asp.net(not that I know asp.net but I am familiar with C# hence). I also would have to make changes to my html code at client side to fetch the Json data from server. I am not really aware of this whole thing. Could someone spare some time and let me know how to go about it? 
3. Does all the client side and server side code lies in a single asp.net project?
 
I have searched over internet. Mostly all the material/coding available over internet is mostly in php or python hence I am confused. There no definite guideline that I could find as how to handle the data part only using JSON?

Comment: Seems like you need to do some basic research about AJAX.

Comment: *"Mostly all the material/coding available over internet is mostly in php or python."* - No it isn't. A lot of people are using Java or C# or Node.js (to name just three alternatives), and that stuff shows up in Google searches too, *especially if you include the desired language in your search criteria*. Try typing "c# ajax tutorial" into Google and go from there (and avoid w3schools). By the way, jQuery isn't a language.

Comment: I will do the search based on Ajax. Thanks for your comments. Could you spare some more time and clear some of my confusion about concepts above asked in queries? thanks in advance.

Comment: Your questions are too broad for this forum. We are here to help you with specific programming problems. Please read this info:http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

to help you answer your 2nd question
2. how can I separate Json from client side code/scripting?
usually server side is in the controller so your HomeController.cs for instance will have an Index action (public ActionResult Index()) that method will basically be called whenever the browser hits the route Home/Index.cshtml
in order to separate these two, you may fetch or construct your Json in the controller and pass it to the ViewBag, from there you can access it in the view.
using $.ajax will help as well to get the json from the view and update the content of a specific part of your page for instance.

Comment: this is all too much knowledge to absorb at this point of time as I am very new to mvc. I will take my time to absorb your solution.

Comment: thank you adnane, I now understand what solution you were trying to suggest.